# CSV writer print the list in one cell

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do a regression analysis and then save the result in a csv file.

Two questions:

1. Why set/list of results coming from regression analysis (`regr.predict` from `sklearn import linear_model`) is being printed in csv in a single cell? I am trying to print every prediction in a separate row one below another (in my case I have 418 results so should be 418 rows in same column).

   ```
   prediction1=regr.predict(xtest)
   with open('my_output_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
       fieldnames=['PassengerId','Survived']
       writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames)
       writer.writeheader()
       for result in prediction1:
           writer.writerow({'PassengerId':'test','Survived':prediction1})
   ```
2. How do I make python write in a certain column or even in a certain cell in csv? (For example, if I want to have a passenger ID in the first column and then have regression results in second column.)

Answer (score 1):

1. You're iterating on the prediction1 with "result" but you write the whole prediction1 on every row:

   ```
   for result in prediction1:
       writer.writerow({'PassengerId':'test','Survived':result})
   ```
2. You are already doing that. You first define the columns and their order (`fieldnames`) and then when you call `writerow()`, you give it a dict with the value for each column and `csv.DictWriter` puts them in the right order.

   You could write:

   ```
   for result in prediction1:
       writer.writerow({'Survived':result, 'PassengerId':'test'})
   ```

And have the same exact result.

Comment: Thank you. First point actually helped. Can't believe I missed it. Second point though, I know that in my example I am already writing in second column. But what if I want to open a completely new file and for some reason enter  a value in cell b3 or range C2:G5. How would I do that?